# Creating a correlation plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a correlation matrix plot with `matplotlib` in python. However I'm not able to make the x and y ticks to be in the middle of each square and also I need the xticks to be vertical. I need them vertical because I will have about 15 variables to plot, so having the ticks in horizontal way won't fit.

Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(10,3)
X = X.T
R = np.corrcoef(X)
plt.figure()
plt.xticks([0,1,2], ["first", "second", "third"], rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks([0,1,2], ["first", "second", "third"])
plt.pcolor(R)
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: I just figured out that using `rotation='vertical'` solves the x-ticks demand for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To centralise the ticks you need to add 0.5 to each value:

```
plt.yticks([0.5,1.5,2.5], ["first", "second", "third"])
plt.xticks([0.5,1.5,2.5], ["first", "second", "third"], rotation='vertical')
```

Also, you might want to add the following so that the overall figure size is adjusted to take account of the rotated x labels:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```